# My code doesn't work outside laravel helper function dd()

Tags: php, laravel

Well.. I can't understand how this could happening but.. my code

```
$parser->mpml->images()->where('order', $parser->figureCounter)->first()->getUrl()
```

didn't work just outside `dd()` helper function. It produce

> Call to a member function getUrl() on null error.

When inside,

```
dd($parser->mpml->images()->where('order', $parser->figureCounter)->first()->getUrl());
```

it works and produce proper url string...? This problem actually happens a week ago, it solved itself even I never do anything. Now, this happens again.

Anyone who have similar experience, would you share your knowledge?

Error must have reason and I can't find a tiny clue on this..

---

```
class FigureSubparser extends Subparser {
    public function start($attrs)
    {
        $this->attrs = $attrs;

        try {
            $order = $this->getEngine()->incFigureCounter()->getFigureCounter();
            $url = $this->getEngine()->mpml->images()->where('order', $order)->first()->getUrl();
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            dd($e->getMessage());
        }

        return '<img src="'.$url.'"/>';
    }
}
```

Above produce `"Call to a member function getImageUrl() on null"`

---

However, when I directly put `$url` part into `dd()`,

```
class FigureSubparser extends Subparser
{
    public function start($attrs)
    {
        $this->attrs = $attrs;

        // try {
            $order = $this->getEngine()->incFigureCounter()->getFigureCounter();
        //  $mpmlimage = $this->getEngine()->mpml->images()->where('order', $order)->first()->getUrl();
        // } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        //  dd($e->getMessage());
        // }

        dd($this->getEngine()->mpml->images()->where('order', $order)->first()->getUrl());

        return '<img src="'.$url.'"/>';
    }
}
```

In this time, `dd()` print out `"http://localhost:8000/mpmlimages/NNYIPFxWz3TQGbtLJB2XEt9g8U8X370BarvRQ7oo.jpeg"` which is what I intended.

and I'm sorry for a wrong answer that my laravel version. It was 5.7.19, not 5.4.

---

After solved.. Report.

The problem is indeed from loop.

While processing, because the `xml_parser` works event driven, every open tag makes another loop.

Each time the open tag is FIGURE element, my custom parser triggers `FigureSubparser->start()`.

Problem is, if there exist parent object that has no image record, since I didn't check the existency of image record, code returns null.

Comment: why both `get()` and `first()` in dd version?

Comment: mistake.. I tried several version of tiny pieces of code..

Comment: which laravel version support getUrl() ? won't able to find anything on official website

Comment: ..oh.. mine is 7.4 and getUrl() is custom method of model. It just return image url string using models attribute. `return 'http://localhost:8000/mpmlimages/'.($this->filename);` is everything inside `getUrl()` method..

Comment: 5.8 is latest available and please do two thing show you custom code too and dd your query result whether you are getting something or not

Comment: can you do a `dd($parser->mpml->images()->where('order', $parser->figureCounter)->first())`

Comment: @GatesPlan  there ???

Comment: Are you running this within a loop?

Comment: @Aditya Thakur ; sure I can. It produce `MpmlImage` model object. It works okay. I do print `dd()` on this line step by step.. and every step works okay..

Comment: Can you check if `$url->getUrl();` throws the same error?

Comment: @George Hanson ; a... probably?? The code is running within `xml_parser`.

Comment: @GatesPlan Can you share how you are calling the `start` method?

Comment: try to print_r and without getUrl so that you can check complete function run and what you are getting

Comment: I'm going to work now. Thanks to everyone! can't sure yet but I think its kinda solve. Thanks to @George Hanson . Try that at night..

Comment: and thanks to @Gaurav Gupta . I didn't filling enough information just before and you keep handling??? me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds likely you are running this within a loop, so it is probably that for one of the results you are querying it is not returning anything. Because of this Laravel will return null which you are then trying to call the `getUrl()` method on.

Instead you should be checking that you have a result before calling the method, such as:

```php
if ($record = $parser->mpml->images()->where('order', $parser->figureCounter)->first()) {
    $url = $record->getUrl();
}
```